# Why compilation fails? [Java]

Tags: java, variables, interface, scope, access-modifiers

```
interface Rideable {

    String getGait();

}

public class Camel implements Rideable {

    String getGait() { return " mph, lope"; }

}
```

Why does the compilation fail? I really don't know why the compile error?

Comment: what do the compilation errors tell you?

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: Interface methods are public by default. You're trying to implement the method with a package private method (which is more restrictive). See [this chart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052) for a comparison between public and package private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the modifier for interface's method is public.  So when you implement it.  It need to be public.  Add public to your getGait method should resolve it

Answer (score 1):

Methods in interface are by default **public and abstract** and data member are by default **public, static and final** as access label. In subclass implementation, you have not mentioned any modifier. So it will have **default** access. While giving the implementation you can't restrict(provide lesser) the access label. So you have to provide public as access modifier while implementing the methods of interface.